# Storing an array of integers with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, erb

I'm trying to take in an array of numbers through the use of a form. In my database I have the variable as:

```
t.integer  "home_goal_min", default: [],  array: true
```

In my form I have:

```
<%= f.label :minutes_of_home_team_goals %>
<%= f.fields_for 'home_goal_min[]', [] do |p| %>
    <%= f.number_field :home_goal_min %>
    <%= f.number_field :home_goal_min %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I also added in the parameter as an array but this still hasn't solved my problem:

```
def result_params
        params.require(:result).permit(:home_result, :away_result, {:home_goal_min => []}, {:away_goal_min => []})
    end
```

However, when I use the form and enter data, I then proceed to check the database through the console but it still appears empty and I just get:
home_goal_min: []

I'm wondering what I need to do to get the numbers entered in the form to be saved in the database?

Also is there a quick way to have the form part for home_goal_min as a text field and allow the user to enter the numbers split by comma, for example as: "23,45,52" would populate home_goal_min with the array [23,45,52]

Answer (score 1):

You have `<%= f.number_field :home_goal_min %>`

Shouldn't it be `<%= p.number_field :home_goal_min %>`?

Edit:

I don't think you can submit Arrays through forms without using javascript. Here's the simplest solution:

In the form:

```
<%= f.text_field :home_goal_mins_list, placeholder: "A comma-separated list of times of the goals" %>
```

In the model:

```
def home_goal_mins_list=(value)
  self.home_goal_mins = value.split(",").map(&:strip)
end

def home_goal_mins_list
  self.home_goal_mins.map(&:to_s).join(", ")
end
```

HOWEVER

If I were you, I would just make this data into its own table. Generally, it's a bad practice to use array fields unless your database is already storing a lot of unstructured data

Comment: well I have my form as `<%= form_for ([@league, @team, @fixture, @result]) do |f| %>` so it should be using it as f.number_field ?

Comment: Nope, within a `fields_for` block, you should be using the field object created in the block. Otherwise, rails has no way of knowing that the field inside that block is supposed to be in the `fields_for` the attribute you're modifying

Comment: ok yeah that makes sense. When I change it to use p.number_field I'm getting an error `undefined method 'home_goal_min' for []:Array`. Am I using the home_goal_min the right way ?

Comment: That's because the names you give fields are the names of attributes rails tries to set on the object, so rails is trying to call `.home_goal_min=' on an array, which isn't possible. If I were you, I'd ditch the nested fields and enter the data in a single field then parse is in the model. Currently updating my answer to explain

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you ***can*** pass in array through a form.
It is done by appending `[]` to the end of the name of the inputs.
For example, your form contains:

```
<input name='home_goal_min[]' value='100'>
<input name='home_goal_min[]' value='200'>
<input name='home_goal_min[]' value='300'>
```

Upon form submission, your params will look like:

```
params[:home_goal_min] => ['100', '200', '300']
```

Docs here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/form_helpers.html
Section `7.1 Basic Structures`

However, reading through your situation, I don't think you need to pass in an array. As Ben noted in his answer, you can parse a single field before saving it. I would suggest doing it in the form object, as model has nothing to do with parsing form data.